# Excel: How to have a cell change color when it has the same value as another cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, colors

I have used conditional formatting to change a row's color for specific values of another cell before but now I want it to change color when the value of a cell is equal to the one next which all have different values.

Is there a formatting method for this too? I have tried `=$AL5"` for example, but it always highlights the cell regardless of the value in the mentioned cell. I would like to do this for a row of cells with each of them highlighting when they are equal to the cell next to them.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Cna you please let us know what you tried? [A quick search](https://www.ecosia.org/search?method=index&q=excel%20conditional%20formatting%20formulas) shows a lot of examples of using conditional formatting with formulas

Comment: Could you provide a sample here?

Comment: I provided an image, I think it explains what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are comparing columns A and B, use the formula below for your conditional formatting rule:

```
=$A1=$B1
```

[image]

**Result**

[image]